# Using Keras to build a LSTM+Conv2D model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, text-classification

I want to build a model similar to this architecture:-
[image]

My current LSTM model is as follows:-

```
x = Embedding(max_features, embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix],trainable=False)(inp)
x = SpatialDropout1D(0.1)(x)
x = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(x)
x = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(64, return_sequences=True))(x)
avg_pool = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
max_pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
conc = concatenate([avg_pool, max_pool])
conc = Dense(64, activation="relu")(conc)
conc = Dropout(0.1)(conc)
outp = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(conc) 
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=outp)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[f1])
```

How to use the Conv2D layer after the BiLSTM later with 2D Max Pooling layer ?

Comment: Is this figure from a paper?
If so, could you please link to it?

Comment: yeah it would be good to see why they decided to use a Conv2D instead of Conv1D?

Answer (score 1):

[Conv2d](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) needs 4D tensor with shape: `(batch, rows, col, channel)`. In NLP problems, unlike computer vision, we do not have a channel. *What can be done?*

We can add an extra dimension with [`expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) function to our Tensors that act as a channel. For example, if our tensor has a shape of `(batch, seq, dim)` then, after expansion, it converts to `(batch, seq, dim, 1)`.

```
lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(embed)
lstm = K.expand_dims(lstm, axis=-1)
conv2d = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, padding='same')(lstm)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few important points you need to pay attention to in order to create this (*fairly complicated*) model.

Here is the model itself, created using the functional API:

```
def expand_dims(x):
    return K.expand_dims(x, -1)

inp = Input(shape=(3,3))
lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(inp)
lstm = Lambda(expand_dims)(lstm)
conv2d = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, padding='same')(lstm)
max_pool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),)(conv2d)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(max_pool)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

### Step by step explanation

**First**, create your input shape. From the image above it looks like you work with 7 samples, a window of 3 and 3 features -> a tensor of shape `(7, 3, 3)`. Obviously you can change to whatever you like. Use the input layer for your bidirectional LSTM layer.

```
inp = Input(shape=(3,3))
lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(inp)
```

**Second**, as @Amir mentioned you need to expand the dimensions if you want to used a `Conv2D` layer. However only using keras backend is not sufficient as the model created by the functional api would require you to have only keras layers in it. Check this answer [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11811#issuecomment-444851244) for error `NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes`. Therefore, you need to extract your `expand_dim` into its own function and wrap around a `Lambda` layer:

```
def expand_dims(x):
    return K.expand_dims(x, -1)

lstm = Lambda(expand_dims)(lstm)
```

**The rest** is pretty straight forward once the above is sorted:

```
conv2d = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, padding='same')(lstm)
max_pool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),)(conv2d)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(max_pool)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

The **summary** of the model looks like:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_67 (InputLayer)        (None, 3, 3)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_29 (Bidirectio (None, 3, 256)            135168    
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_7 (Lambda)            (None, 3, 256, 1)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)           (None, 3, 256, 128)       640       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_14 (MaxPooling (None, 1, 128, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_207 (Dense)            (None, 1, 128, 10)        1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 137,098
Trainable params: 137,098
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

And here is the **visualisation**:

[image]